# SSIS csv file with noisi commas

Tags: sql-server, excel, csv, ssis

I am quite new on using SSIS dtsx on SQL server 2005.
I have CSV files that have been cleansed removing extra commas (in text fields) opening the CSV file in excel and using a replace command.
The problem is that I cannot do the same thing in SSIS as the CSV file cannot be opened with the Excel Connection Manager.

How Can I handle this problem?
Thanks in advance for your help,
Damien

Comment: how are the csvs populated? do u have control over that?

Comment: Cleanse the columns before populating into CSVs. . You can do it using Replace statements . . like Select replace(colname,',','') from tablename

Comment: if you have no control on the csvs, you need to use a script task and find regex patterns and edit the file. you can post a sample row of data